# Superclass and subclass, diffrent function calls depending on subclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism, subclass, conditional-statements, superclass

Been stuck on this problem a while, and can't seem to find any answers!

I want to have baseclass (figure) and a number of sublcasses (circle, triangle etc..). Then I want a vector to contain diffrent kinds of subclasses.

The thing is, all my subclasses have sizes, but they are described in diffrent ways.

A circle only need a radius, while a triangle needs a base and height, and a square needs width and height.

**This is my superclass**

```
class Figure {
  public:
    //This function should take diffrent amount of values
    virtual void setSize();
 //More awesome stuff here
}
```

**These are example subclasses**

```
class Circle {

  public:
      //This is a circle, only needs radius as size
     void setSize( int _radius ) { radius = _radius; }

 };

class Triangle {

   public:
   //This is a triangle, it needs both a base and height
    void setSize( int _base, int _height ) { base = _base; height = _height; }
};
```

So now if I call getSize() from my Figure* and its pointing to a Circle object, is there anyway of making my superclass know its the setSize( double ) in the Circle class it should call?

Comment: Not if they don't have the same parameter types - is this actual code? Because if it is you're never going to get polymorphic behaviour out of your Figure class at all - there are no overrides of `setSize()` since they all have different parameters.

Comment: You should try to find another properties to describe your polymorphic object: What about `virtual void Figure::setScale(double);` and `virtual void setXYRatio(double,double)`

Comment: You could use default arguments as a hack and just ignore other arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Its as simple as this: If your classes do not have anything in common inheritance wont work.
What do you expect to happen? If I enter `base->setSize(3)` for a `Triangle` what behaviour do you expect?

If you can work with this parameter though, you simple have to override the function in your child class. In case you want to call your more specialized `setSize(int, int)` function from this overriden version you can write:

```
void setSize(int _radius) {
    setSize(_radius, _radius);
}
```

This is ofcourse only an example, you can do whatever you desire with the parameters before passing them into you more specialized method.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, warning: if you store derived classes in a vector you will slice your objects. Remember that the STL uses copying to move data members around. So if you have a `vector<superclass>` and try to store a child class object, the STL will copy the superclass part of your object into its own memory and leave your specialisation.

To get around this your first instinct would be to use a pointer to the object and store that pointer. This will open a can of worms with memory leaks just waiting to happen. The solution is to store a smart pointer from the Boost library. I suggest you read “Beyond the C++ Standard Library – An introduction to Boost” by Bjoern Karlsson. Chapter 1: smart_ptr

Like Paranaix I have some difficulty envisioning the use of your class tree interface by clients. In similar type “Figure” implementations, getSize() type functions usually return a bounding box. The superclass would provide a virtual function Draw() to paint the figure inside that bounding box.

As Pananaix indicates, the idea with polymorphic functions is that the function represents one narrowly bounded idea which is implemented in different ways in derived classes. (this is the separation of interface and implementation principle)

In your design a client has to know the type of object in order to call/interpret the result of one function getSize(). (For a triangle you are returning/setting sides, for a circle a radius) This is not the way to go.

My best advice is to look at your design and try to develop an interface and write against that interface. Once the interface works, write the implementations.

Good luck.

Comment: With C++11 one should rather use a `std::unique_ptr` than a Boost smart pointer if polymorphic behavior is the only goal (e.g. no shared ownership required).